# Javascript 'Promise' how to make Synchronous

Tags: javascript, sqlite, typescript

I am using Ionic2/Typescript.

I have 2 `Promise`'s that I want to have complete, before I continue (i.e synchronous).  So I put the call to the 2 functions in a `Promise.all(...)`, expecting them to complete before `resolve` is called.

I have the following code:

```
public openDatabase(): Promise<Array<Message>> {
    let promise: Promise<Array<Message>> = new Promise<Array<Message>>(resolve => {
        if (false && this.database && this.database != null) {
            Promise.all([this.refreshChats(this.database), this.refreshMessages(this.database)]).then(() => {
                console.log('openDatabase1: resolve');
                resolve(this.messages);
            });
        } else {
            this.database = new SQLite();
            this.database.openDatabase({
                name: "data.db",
                location: "default"
            }).then(() => {
                Promise.all([this.refreshChats(this.database), this.refreshMessages(this.database)]).then(() => {
                    console.log('openDatabase2: resolve');
                    resolve(this.messages);
                });
            }, (error) => {
                console.log("OPEN ERROR: ", error);
            });
        }
    });
    return promise;
}

public refreshChats(db: any): Promise<any> {
    console.log('refreshChats ');
    return db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM chats", [])
        .then((chatData) => {
            let promises: Array<any> = [];
            this.chats = [];
            if (chatData.rows.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < chatData.rows.length; i++) {
                    promises.push(this.populateChat(db, chatData.rows.item(i)));
                }
            }
            Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                console.log('refreshChats return this.chats.length = ' + this.chats.length);
                return this.chats;
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("ERROR REFRESHING CHATS: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

From my console output, you can see that `resolve` is called before the chats are finished refreshing:

> ```
> refreshChats
> populateChat  Object {...}
> openDatabase2: resolve
> refreshChats return this.chats.length = 1
> ```

Any advise on how I should structure my `Promises` is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return new promises from inner promise callbacks:

```
public openDatabase(): Promise<Array<Message>> {
    let promise: Promise<Array<Message>> = new Promise<Array<Message>>(resolve => {
        if (false && this.database && this.database != null) {
            return Promise.all([this.refreshChats(this.database), this.refreshMessages(this.database)]).then(() => {
                console.log('openDatabase1: resolve');
                resolve(this.messages);
            });
        } else {
            this.database = new SQLite();
            return this.database.openDatabase({
                name: "data.db",
                location: "default"
            }).then(() => {
                return Promise.all([this.refreshChats(this.database), this.refreshMessages(this.database)]).then(() => {
                    console.log('openDatabase2: resolve');
                    resolve(this.messages);
                });
            }, (error) => {
                console.log("OPEN ERROR: ", error);
            });
        }
    });
    return promise;
}

public refreshChats(db: any): Promise<any> {
    console.log('refreshChats ');
    return db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM chats", [])
        .then((chatData) => {
            let promises: Array<any> = [];
            this.chats = [];
            if (chatData.rows.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < chatData.rows.length; i++) {
                    promises.push(this.populateChat(db, chatData.rows.item(i)));
                }
            }
            return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                console.log('refreshChats return this.chats.length = ' + this.chats.length);
                return this.chats;
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("ERROR REFRESHING CHATS: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Note, `return Promise.all` and `return this.database.openDatabase`.